# Copying Multiple Files at once

Tags: copy, syncback

I have a huge storage that I need to duplicate to another storage. Both storages have 10G of NIC cards. So a good bandwidth. To do this I'm using SyncbackPro. But this is copying single file at a time. I did select the option to be multithreaded. But that's for using multiple CPU cycles, to make it quicker. But what I'm looking for is to open up multiple copying of files at once. So it can fully utilize the bandwidth.

Any ideas !

Comment: I have Sync Back Pro here.  Set it to the top of your folder structure and make a profile to back this up (Mirror).  I use this and that should work.

Comment: It works but takes 1 file at a time. I need to take multiple files. Like opening different streams of copy at once. How to achieve this

Comment: Try making a Sync Back Profile that includes a top level folder with all your files. You can put folders in Groups of folders. I have 3 Groups. I can make a connection to a new computer and sync or mirror hundreds of files at one go.  The key is to set up a folder or folders in Groups in a profile to copy or sync files (Sync Back will do both).

Answer (score 0):

> I have a huge storage that I need to duplicate to another storage

(1) Make sure you have a top level folder or a small number of folders that hold all your files.

(2) With Sync Back, you can create a New Profile setting up the Source machine and the Target machine.  You can (in Sync Back) group Profiles into Groups which makes selective copying (mirroring) or syncing (comparing and updating) individual groups.  Sync Back can create new folders on the target computer if the folder is new on the Source computer.

(3) Make sure the Source computer and Target computer are connected so you can share files.

(4) Once set up, click on the Profile or Group and select Run.

I keep hundreds (thousands) of files in 6 main folders and can (once) backup (mirror) to a new computer and (daily) sync two computers to make sure all is up to date.

I use Sync Back every day and have done so for over a decade to make sure files are properly created and backed up.

[image]